# Java, stopping (interrupting) the thread

Tags: java, multithreading

Very recently I've asked this question, but wasn unable to fix this. So I have a thread hunter (2 of them actually), who "goes off to catch wild boars". He stores these boars in a container Fridge. He will continue to do so until his working hours expire. However, in case the Fridge is full he has to wait. The aim is to wait until a wild boar is removed from the fridge, but if it takes more then 5 seconds of waiting test must be terminated. So everything works except one thing. After running test and interrupting these threads, the program still continues to run. So how do I completely terminate/stop these threads?

TEST CLASS (main)

```
class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test1();
    }

    public static void test1() {

        Fridge fridge = new Fridge(4);

        Hunter hunter1 = new Hunter("hunter1", 4, fridge);
        Hunter hunter2 = new Hunter("hunter2", 7, fridge);
        Thread hunterThread1 = new Thread(hunter1);
        Thread hunterThread2 = new Thread(hunter2);
        hunterThread1.start();
        hunterThread2.start();

        try { Thread.sleep(1000); } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        hunterThread1.interrupt();
        hunterThread2.interrupt();
        System.out.println(fridge.getSize());
        System.out.println(hunter1.getWorkTime());
        System.out.println(hunter2.getWorkTime());
    }
}
```

HUNTER CLASS

```
class Hunter extends Worker {

    private int workTime;
    private Fridge fridge;

    public Hunter(String name, int workTime, Fridge fridge) {
        super(name);
        this.workTime = workTime;
        this.fridge = fridge;
    }

    public int getWorkTime() {
        return workTime;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (workTime > 0) {
            /** Each hunt takes a random amount of time (1-50 ms) **/
            try { Thread.sleep(workGen()); } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            /** Add new wild boars **/
            try { fridge.add(new WildBoar()); } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            workTime--;
            /** If thread is interupted break the loop **/
            if( Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

FRIDGE CLASS

```
import java.util.Stack;

class Fridge extends Storage {

    private Stack<WildBoar> boars;

    public Fridge(int cap) {
        super(cap);
        boars = new Stack<WildBoar>();
    }

    public int getCap() {
        return cap;
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return boars.size();
    }

    public boolean hasFreeSpace() {
        if ( boars.size() < cap )
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public synchronized void add(WildBoar boar) throws InterruptedException {
        /** If there's no free space available wait **/
        while ( !hasFreeSpace() ) {
            wait();
        }
        /** Once there's free space available add new item **/
        boars.add(boar);

    }

    public synchronized WildBoar remove() {
        return boars.pop();
    }

}
```

ADDITIONAL CLASSES FOR COMPILING:

```
abstract class Worker implements Runnable {

    private String name;

    public Worker(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int workGen() {
        return 1 + (int)(Math.random() * (50 - 1));
    }
}

class WildBoar {

    public WildBoar() {}
}

abstract class Storage {

    protected int cap;

    public Storage(int cap) {
        this.cap = cap;
    }

    public int getCap() {
        return cap;
    }
}
```

Comment: The given code is not enough to compile it, for instance what is workGen() method in Hunter class. Could you show all relevant code necessary to compile the program?

Comment: @bbaja42 I added additional classes

Comment: Also, note that threads will not exit immediately after you try to stop them, but only when check statement ( Thread.isInterrupted) is called.

Comment: @bbaja42 so how exactly can I stop them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you `interrupt()` the thread which is currently waiting, the native wait method will actually reset the interruption flag.  So when you evaluate the `isInterrupted()` here, it is actually reset and will appear as not interrupted.

```
if( Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
     break;
}
```

You will have to re-interrupt the thread after an interruption occurs during the `wait`ing

```
public synchronized void add(Object boar) {
    /** If there's no free space available wait **/
    while (!hasFreeSpace()) {
     try{
         wait();
     }catch(InterruptedException e){ 
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); 
        return; //or rethrow
     }
    }
    /** Once there's free space available add new item **/
    boars.add(boar);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Currently, the `run` method in your `Hunter` thread is discarding interruptions:

```
try { fridge.add(new WildBoar()); }
 catch (InterruptedException e) {}
```

Thus, nothing happens when you later check for interruptions

```
if( Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
    break;
}
```

To correct this, you need to set the thread's [interrupt status](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29):

```
try { fridge.add(new WildBoar()); }
 catch (InterruptedException e) {
  Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
 }
```

Summary - ignoring the `InterruptedException` resets the interrupt status. If you don't or re-throw it or `break`, then you will need to set the interrupt status manually.